# Copy file if condition is true

Tags: java, file, apache-camel

Camel. File component. I need to configure route so that it copy file only if no errors happened. What I have:

```
<route id="importFile" autoStartup="{{fdr.import.enabled}}">
            <from uri="direct:startImportFile"/>
            <from uri="file://{{fdr.folder.working}}?delete=true&amp;readLock=changed"/>
            <transacted ref="fdrTxRequired"/>
            <doTry>
                <to uri="file://{{fdr.folder.done}}"/> <!--1-->
                <bean ref="transactionsProcessor"/>
                <bean ref="transactionsFinalizer"/>
                <!--2-->
                <doCatch>
                    <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
                    <to uri="file://{{fdr.folder.failed}}"/>
                    <bean ref="exceptionProcessor"/>
                </doCatch>
                <doFinally>
                    <bean ref="responsePublisher"/>
                </doFinally>
            </doTry>
        </route>
```

Required logic:
If everething were processed ok in transactionsProcessor and transactionsFinalizer then we just moved file from folder 'working' to folder 'done'
If errors occured in transactionProcessor or transactionsFinalizer then we move file from 'working' to 'failed' and 'done' must be empty
If I put row 1 to placeholder 2 than I can't relocate file as InputStream after processing in my custom processors.
Maybe we can move from 'working' to 'done'. Then we process file if ok then ok. If errors occured then move from 'done' to 'failed'. Help pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ou, I found solution - multicast with stopOnExeption

```
<routeContext id="fileImportOnlyRouteContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route id="importFile" autoStartup="{{fdr.import.enabled}}">
            <from uri="direct:startImportFile"/>
            <from uri="file://{{fdr.folder.working}}?delete=true&amp;readLock=changed"/>
            <transacted ref="fdrTxRequired"/>
            <doTry>
                <multicast stopOnException="true">
                    <to uri="direct:startFileImporter"/>
                    <to uri="file://{{fdr.folder.done}}"/>
                </multicast>
                <doCatch>
                    <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
                    <to uri="file://{{fdr.folder.failed}}"/>
                    <bean ref="exceptionProcessor"/>
                </doCatch>
                <doFinally>
                    <bean ref="responsePublisher"/>
                </doFinally>
            </doTry>
        </route>

        <route id="fileImporterRoute">
            <from uri="direct:startFileImporter"/>
            <bean ref="transactionsProcessor"/>
            <bean ref="transactionsFinalizer"/>
        </route>
    </routeContext>
```